# Input type number increment using scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having some hard time figuring out how to implement "input type number" increment using scroll feature.

My question may sound confusing, so I attached an example.

[image]

**Live preview: https://webuyfiredamagedhouses.com/cash-offer/**

Comment: Please don't post links to your code. Post the code here in your question.

Comment: Just google. There are so many results for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Using a plugin called Quantity controller: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Numeric-Stepper-Quantity-Controller/